# Looking for pattern recognition and prediction for my data using machine learning

Tags: regression, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

I have a bunch of data containing response times of a network service.  I want to use that data to predict future down times. Before a service goes down the response time will increase about 1-45 minutes ahead of time. I have a response time every 3 minutes and I would like to predict if a certain increase in response time (pattern) might cause down time and when that down time is going to happen.

Are there any machine learning algorithms that can solve this? I've been looking at all types of regression modules like linear and decision tree but I'm not sure what I should use for this.

Data looks something like this (Example data) :

```
50ms - 52ms - 48ms - 25ms - 35ms - 45ms - 60ms - 75ms - 79ms - 85ms - 80ms - 90ms - 130ms - 115ms - 150ms - 163ms - 210ms - 190ms - 230ms - DOWN - DOWN - 50ms (someone had been notified it has been down for 2 "pings" and fixed it)
```

Comment: You're using sequence data to predict a binary outcome. Sounds like a some variety of RNN would work.

Comment: Is it possible to predict a time when the service is going down with RNN?

Comment: Probably. An even better way would be to estimate a probability distribution over durations.

Comment: @Sycorax I'm pretty new to this. I've also looked at probabilistic classification but I'm really not sure which is the right one to go with. "estimate a probability distribution over durations" Can you give me some starting points as to how I would go about doing this?